# Is this proof that a homomorphism preserves identities correct (sufficient)?

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, group-homomorphism

My textbook writes the following proof for the statement in the title:

> For a homomorphism $\varphi:G \to G'$ and any $g\in G$, $\varphi(g) = \varphi(ge) = \varphi(g)\varphi(e)$. Multiplying both sides of this equation on the left by $(\varphi(g))^{−1}$ gives the desired result, $e′ = e′\varphi(e) = \varphi(e)$.

It's not clear to me why we should be able to work like this. In particular, we only have that $\varphi(g) = \varphi(g)\varphi(e)$ for all elements in $G'$ of the form $\varphi(g)$. But it seems like the proof is tacitly using that $e'$ is the unique element for which $e'g' = g'$ for all $g \in G'$...and yet we haven't shown that $\varphi(e)$ actually does this for every $g'$!

Comment: No, this is not tacitly assumed. We just take the equation $\phi(g)=\phi(g)\phi(e)$ and cancel the invertible element $\phi(g)$. But $\phi(g)\cdot \phi(g)^{-1}=1$ in $G'$, and the $1$ is the $e'$. We obtain $e'=1=\phi(e)$. Take for example $G=G'=\Bbb Z$ and $\phi(n)=2n$.

Comment: Use `$\varphi$` for $\varphi$ and `$\in$` for $\in$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I guess I am looking for an argument which doesn't just say "cancel" but shows what that means. For example, suppose we have the lemma that in a group $G$, if $gh = gk$ then $h=k$.. Computing, we have $h = eh = (g^{-1}g)h = g^{-1}(gh) = g^{-1}(gk) = (g^{-1}g) k = ek = k. $ I was trying to convince myself using this more direct line.

Comment: Cancelling in a group really means $g\cdot g^{-1}=e$, so $gh=gh'$ gives $h=h'$. This is all. So it is just the existence of $g^{-1}$. The cancelling in  the multiplicative group of a field, say, of real numbers is the same. If $2a=2b$, then $a=b$, because $2$ has an inverse $1/2$, which we can multiply from the left.

Comment: In a group, if $xy=x$ for a single $x$, then $y=e$.

Comment: And this is also cancelling, since we could view it as $xy=x=xe$ implies $y=e$.

Comment: Got it, thanks to everyone for the clarification.

Comment: **Slight variation of proof:** By homomorphism, $\varphi (e)= \varphi (e^2)= \varphi(e) \varphi(e)$. By cancellation law, $\varphi(e)=e’$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because **every** element in a group has an inverse, it's enough for

$$fg' = g'$$

for **just one** $g'\in G'$ to prove that $f$ is the identity.

The fact that we already know that $G'$ is a group has done most of the work for us - we know that there is an element in $G'$ that preserves every element when you multiply by it, we just have to show that that's what $\varphi$ maps $e$ to.

Comment: Ah I see. I think I can use the lemma I proved in the comments above to show this?

Comment: Yup, that lemma is a great proof. And it's exactly what mathematicians mean when they say "cancel" in a group setting. :-)

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Comment: As an aside, does this mean that if we relax the "for any $g \in G$" and talk about a map such that for exactly one $g \in G$ we have $f(g) = f(ge) = f(g)f(e)$ then $f$ preserves identities?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I understand what you are asking., especially with the "exactly one $g$" specification.  $f(g) = f(ge)$ automatically for all $g \in G$, not just one. - that's $e$ being the identity in $G$. And $f(ge) = f(g)f(e)$ is also true for all $g$ - that's what being a homomorphism is. If you're asking if we can have weaker assumptions than having a group identity or the homomorphism rule, and still deduce preserving identities, then maybe you should check out monoids or semi-groups and see how things that work in groups can stop working in those structures.

Comment: Yes, I was asking about $f$ where $f$ is not a homomorphism; $f(ge) = f(g)f(e)$ only for some $g$. At any rate, I will take a peek at those structures -- thank you!